# Can different endpoints be used for each resource in WSO2?

Tags: wso2

I am trying to create an API proxy for a backend to restify the API.

I used the solution given below to map the requests.

https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/deploy-and-publish/deploy-on-gateway/api-gateway/message-mediation/mapping-the-parameters-of-your-backend-urls-with-the-api-publisher-urls/

I can map requests like this example:

From

localhost:XXXX/api/abc/5

To

xyz.com/api/?function=getabc&number=5

However,I need to create different endpoints for each resource to make this approach work. However, it seems like only one endpoint is used for the whole API. I also cannot create different APIs for each resource because the context would be different.

How can I create different request mappings for each resource. Is my approach wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try dynamic endpoints feature. You can have multiple endpoints per API using this Feature. When creating the API you need to set the Endpoint Type as "Dynamic Endpoint" and upload a mediation in-sequence that sets the "To" header. Within the sequence, you can specify your logic to route to the correct endpoint (setting the correct "To" header) according to the request path.

https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/deploy-and-publish/deploy-on-gateway/api-gateway/message-mediation/adding-dynamic-endpoints/#adding-dynamic-endpoints

Here is a blog post explaining the same for 2.x versions of APIM.
https://lashan.medium.com/dynamically-setting-the-endpoint-uri-in-wso2-api-manager-83a3a6243ce

Comment: I am not sure how I can check the request path and map each one to an endpoint in XML.

Comment: I managed to utilize dynamic endpoints with switch case.